# Rails resource route under namespace leading to "not a supported controller name."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm building an API in Rails and I'd like for it to be versioned. My `routes.rb` file consists of:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :V1 do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

And I have my controller under `/app/controllers/V1/users_controller.rb`, which has this content:

```
module V1
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
      render json: {message: "This is a test!"}
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to run the rails server on the command line I get the following error:

```
`default_controller_and_action': 'V1/users' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use
```

I've looked at the link the error message gave me, however it seems to be how to specify a controller to use with a resource. Rather than doing that, can Rails not automatically determine it from my directory structure?

Comment: Try a lowercase namespace (:v1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users
  end
end
```